# Disabled TLSv1.0 and TLSv1.1 on Window

Tags: apache, ssl, tls1.0, tls1.1

I want to enable TLS 1.2 in Window Server.

I have edited the C:/apache2/conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf, adding

SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1

SSLCipherSuite HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5:!3DES

SSLHonorCipherOrder on

but still Apache is using tls 1.0. Is it possible to activate tls 1.2?

The Apache version is Apache/2.2.34
and openSSL version is 1.0.2

TLSv1.0 and TLSv1.1 is disabled.